# Segmentation Error : Command Arguments (argv)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments, cs50

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
  if (argc == 2)
  {
    printf ("%s \n", argv[1]);
    
    if (isdigit (argv[1]) !=0)
     {
        printf("Success\n");
        printf("%s \n", argv[1]);
     }
    else
     {
        printf(" %s key \n", argv[0]);
     }
  }
     else
     {
        printf(" %s key \n", argv[0]);
     }

}
```

Hello everyone, I am trying to run this program that takes command line arguments and checks them for digits.After that I have to store it into a variable. I am stuck and it is giving the error "Segmentation fault". I googled it and I think it means that the program is not able to read the value. Please let me know why it is giving the error, what "Segmentation fault" means and how to fix it.

Comment: @SaiSreenivas note the cs50 header,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is in

```
 isdigit (argv[1])
```

`argv[1]` is of type `char *`, but [`isdigit()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit) expects an `int`.

If you want to check whether the supplied argument is all-numerical value or not, you have to either

- Loop over the elements in `argv[n]` and pass them one by one to `isdigit()` check.
- use [`strtol()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) or similar to check for the validity.

Answer (score 1):

The error in on line 13,
You need to do a

```
...
13: if (isdigit (atoi(argv[1])) != 0)
...
```

Comment: `atoi()` is particularly bad for various reasons. use `strtol()` for better.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The function [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) expects the **character code** of a single character, for example an ASCII code. The function `atoi` does not return such a character code. Passing a value larger than `UCHAR_MAX` (normally 255) or smaller than 0 to the function `isdigit` will cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), unless that value happens to be the value for `EOF` (which is unlikely).